# Errors while running Repair

Tags: cassandra

I see below errors in the log while running repair. Any suggestions?

ERROR: Repair service needs to run 5 range repairs in parallel; maximum is 3. The repair cannot complete without adversely affecting the cluster. Data left: 789372891769.64, time left: 777483.00, required throughput: 835224.55, actual throughput: 227588.69.

Comment: I am using DSE 4.5.1 and running repair using Opscenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below parameters to opscenterd.conf and restart the Opscenter

[repair_service]
max_parallel_repairs = 5